How to navigate between fragments present in different nav-graph in navigation component?
How to navigate between nav-graph fragments in android navigation component?


How can we use action of a global fragments and navigate to other nav-graph fragment?
How can we navigate from one nav-graph fragment to other nav-graph fragment where destination is not the start destination?

In below code how to navigate from

fragment_A present in car_nav_graph to frgament_D present in bike_nav_graph
fragment_E present in main_nav_graph to frgament_B present in car_nav_graph

Main nav graph
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/car_nav_graph">

<include app:graph="@navigation/car_nav_graph" />

<include app:graph="@navigation/bike_nav_graph" />  

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_E”
    android:name=“com.fragment_E”
    android:label=“Fragment E”>
    <argument
        android:name=“mode”
        app:argType=“string” />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/fragment_E_to_fragment_B”
        app:destination="@id/fragment_B”>
        <argument
            android:name=“mode”
            app:argType=“string” />
    </action>
</fragment>

</navigation>  

Car nav graph
<navigation 
    android:id="@+id/car_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_A>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_A"
    android:name=“com.fragment_A”
    android:label=“Fragment A">
    <argument
        android:name=“mode”
        app:argType=“string” />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/fragment_A_to_fragment_D”
        app:destination="@id/fragment_D”>
        <argument
            android:name=“mode”
            app:argType=“string” />
    </action>
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_B"
    android:name=“com.fragment_B”
    android:label=“Fragment B">
    <argument
        android:name=“mode”
        app:argType=“string” />
</fragment>

<include app:graph="@navigation/bike_nav_graph" />

</navigation> 

Bike nav graph
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bike_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_C>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_C”
    android:name=“com.fragment_C”
    android:label=“Fragment C”>
    <argument
        android:name=“mode”
        app:argType=“string” />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_D”
    android:name=“com.fragment_D”
    android:label=“Fragment D”>
    <argument
        android:name=“mode”
        app:argType=“string” />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/fragment_D_to_fragment_E”
        app:destination="@id/fragment_E”>
        <argument
            android:name=“mode”
            app:argType=“string” />
    </action>
</fragment>

</navigation>```

